# SwiftUI API Decode

Tags: function, api, swiftui

I'm trying to decode a JSON response from Yelp on business details. The JSON response comes back like this:

```
{
"id": "ATaQ4GLQisXA7tylsJobhQ",
"alias": "chicken-fire-orlando",
"name": "Chicken Fire",
"image_url": "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/YMkiKEv-WApzbJZ321rsEg/o.jpg",
"is_claimed": true,
"is_closed": false,
"url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/chicken-fire-orlando?adjust_creative=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_lookup&utm_source=s-hyKAjsx6P4UW-uqMn7aQ",
"phone": "",
"display_phone": "",
"review_count": 107,
"categories": [
    {
        "alias": "chickenshop",
        "title": "Chicken Shop"
    }
],
"rating": 5.0,
"location": {
    "address1": "2406 E Washington St",
    "address2": "",
    "address3": null,
    "city": "Orlando",
    "zip_code": "32803",
    "country": "US",
    "state": "FL",
    "display_address": [
        "2406 E Washington St",
        "Orlando, FL 32803"
    ],
    "cross_streets": ""
},
"coordinates": {
    "latitude": 28.5438637820401,
    "longitude": -81.3516076281667
},
"photos": [
    "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/YMkiKEv-WApzbJZ321rsEg/o.jpg",
    "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/gLcMNuoaJonieGFsSS9qeA/o.jpg",
    "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/oWAPiL4nQLab-PrrEoQ30A/o.jpg"
],
"hours": [
    {
        "open": [
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1200",
                "end": "1500",
                "day": 3
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1700",
                "end": "2000",
                "day": 3
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1200",
                "end": "1500",
                "day": 4
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1700",
                "end": "2000",
                "day": 4
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1200",
                "end": "1500",
                "day": 5
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1700",
                "end": "2000",
                "day": 5
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1200",
                "end": "1500",
                "day": 6
            },
            {
                "is_overnight": false,
                "start": "1700",
                "end": "2000",
                "day": 6
            }
        ],
        "hours_type": "REGULAR",
        "is_open_now": true
    }
],
"transactions": [
    "delivery",
    "pickup"
]
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I just want to pull back 3 easy things.

```swift
struct BusinessDetails: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let image_url: String
}


public class Api: ObservableObject {
    func getDetails(completion: @escaping (BusinessDetails) -> ()) {
        let apikey = "API KEY HERE"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/ATaQ4GLQisXA7tylsJobhQ")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(apikey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, _, _) in
            let details = try! JSONDecoder().decode(BusinessDetails.self, from: data!)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(details)
                print("Below are details")
                print(details)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And I see that I'm able to grab the information that I want to display in my view, but I obviously have the syntax when calling my function wrong.

I'm using:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct Details: View {
    @State var details: [BusinessDetails] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.vertical/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(details) { detail in
                VStack {
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: detail.image_url))
                        .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
                    }
                    .resizable()
                    .placeholder(Image(systemName: "photo"))
                        
                    .placeholder {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .indicator(.activity)
                    .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 250)
                    .clipped()
                }.padding(.vertical, 8)
            }.onAppear {
                Api().getDetails { (details) in
                    self.details = details
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Print in my function shows:

```
"BusinessDetails(id: "ATaQ4GLQisXA7tylsJobhQ", name: "Chicken Fire", image_url: "https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/YMkiKEv-WApzbJZ321rsEg/o.jpg")"
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. The only thing resembling an problem/question is this sentence "but I obviously have the syntax when calling my function wrong" - which syntax are you talking about

Comment: The error is in my onAppear statement. It's not returning any data to my view.

Comment: "Cannot assign value of type 'BusinessDetails' to type [BusinessDetails]

Comment: the property `details` of your `Details` view is an array. So, either change it to just be of type `BusinessDetails` or append to that array `self.details.append(details)` in the completion block